# Merging dev and live prestashop databases

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have extensive modifications to carry out on a prestashop 1.6 site.

I have created a local copy, and am tracking filesystem changes in git.

However a lot of changes in prestashop are stored in the database, specifically in my case:

- Installing and configuring a new module
- Uninstalling a module
- Adding shop categories and changing the hierarchy
- Changing module positions
- and generally modifying what modules appear in what hooks.

During the dev process, the live site has received numerous new orders, customers, subscribers etc, so the databases are out of sync.

I have solved similar problems in other frameworks by dumping and importing specific tables in the db, or using the frameworks built in migrations functionality, but i cannot find any advise specifically for prestashop.

How is this handled?

Considering that the dev site has probably undergone more diverse changes than the live one, i wonder if it would be easier to copy the new orders etc over to the dev site then overwrite the whole thing?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it is possible to achieve this in PrestaShop. You must have immense knowledge of PrestaShop DB (i.e. have knowledge of each and every table and columns in it) to merge the databases.

It is never recommended to do that either.

I suggest you do the syncing manually as it is a very risky task and you might lose all the data in your live store, which will be even more painful.

Comment: Urgh, not what i wanted to hear, but thanks anyway. I would have put the store into maintenence mode and backed up the files and DB before attempting a merge anyway, but doing all this manually through the backoffice is going to mean having the store offline for a number of hours, which will be costly in lost sales

Answer (score 2):

For modules the information is stored in all tables which start with `modules`.
Module config values are stored in `configuration` and `configuration_lang`. Make sure you also copy custom module tables of course.

Shop categories information is in all tables which start with `category`.

Module hooks information is in all tables which start with `hook`.

However as Raghubendra Singh said in his answer this is very risky task, if you really really want to do it, I suggest you create another local copy of currently live site and first try the process between two local copies and make sure everything works correctly.

Comment: Ok, thats promising, i might be able to write a bash script with some carefull local testing. It will probably take more developer time up front than just changing in the backoffice, but the reduced downtime is likely to cover that, even if not in the 1st instance, it should eventually pay for its self. And not having to work at 3am is a plus!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you my experience on updating the Prestashop and using it everyday.

For the everyday work (fix bug or add feature) I do the changes in DB directly in phpmyadmin. I test everything in a mirror isntallation, copy the changes to the prod site and apply the mysql changes.

We only lauched 2-3 new major versions of the site (once every 2 years, more or less) and wait for a stable version of Prestashop, even 1.7 now has a few major bugs (Translations was one of them, not sure it's 100% fixed in 1.7.1).
The last one, that went quite well, we altered the theme to our needs, applied a bunch of new features for our customers, etc... When was time to launch I just analysed the difference in the relevant tables, and copied the data from the old db to the new one, with the added fields and changed defaults, etc...  using ssh access as they were both on the same server.

Btw, the old tables we need were related to address, carrier, cart, category, customer, delivery, feature, group, image (but not image_type), manufacturer, orders, product, range, specific_price, stock_available, supplier, tax, tax_rule, wishlist, zone, country, state, employee, profile, and others used by our modules. Others like modules, configuration, hooks, etc, didn't matter because it was a complete new theme.

I always thought on doing something that could synchronize the db of the dev version and live one. But still haven't done due to the fact that we don't do that many major changes, and the minor ones, we try to keep the changes in a file until we apply it (not the most professional, I know). And sometimes, on these major version changes there could be new ways of Prestashop doing things. THe last i remember was the access slug in the 1.6.something, that was not in the 1.5, and after everything done, I could login to back office, but other workers couldn't, because it had changed how access was controlled, and since I was superadmin, I was not affected by it. Another thing in the of not doing it right now, it that Prestashop is starting to use Symfony, and I think will try to use it even more in the future, impacting how things are going to be done in the future. So a solution now could not work in the future.

We could also use the upgrade features in modules. Never tried it, but it could be used to apply upgrades to the DB and others automatically. Looks promising, but don't know if it works with a push or if only on module upgrade. One of these days i'm going to test this.

This is not a response with a solution, but I'm interested in one, and in working on one if there isn't any. It would be interesting to do a push, and not having to change things in db "by hand".

Comment: Unless the module is on Prestashop Addons, the upgrade will run as soon as you load modules list page. You also need to modify all original install sql code/files to reflect the changes because the upgrade scripts will run only once ie. if you reinstall the module, the upgrade scripts will not run.

Comment: That's good to know. Maybe the push/pull could trigger an upgrade check on each module. On reinstall, the upgrade would have happened. And on install, we needed to change the code to create the table to mirror the latest structure.

Comment: that's just theory

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @sadlyblue When you have comments under your answer by more than two different people you need to use `@username` so he gets notification about your comment.